# MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method toggle on channel wakelock) - Flutter wakelock

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

I get this error in debug console when I use wakelock:

```
E/flutter (17630): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method toggle on channel wakelock)
```

Here's my code:

```
import 'package:wakelock/wakelock.dart';

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
bool on = true;
// The following statement enables the wakelock.
 void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Wakelock.toggle(on: on);
}
```

Also I do have this added in my AndroidManifest.xml     `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />`

And this in dependencies : `wakelock: ^0.1.4+2`

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. Please make sure that you have flutter and dart updated because it looks like the plugin has bugs in some versions. I updated flutter to 1.20.3 ( dart 2.9.2) and now everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

stop the debugger, do 'flutter clean' in the terminal and restart the app.